# .Net WCF class and conversion to JSON

Tags: json, wcf

I have the following classes in my WCF app -

```
[DataContract(Name = "RootObject")]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public MainDataSet dataset { get; set; }


}



[DataContract(Name = "MainDataSeta")]
public class MainDataSet
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public List<Dimension> dimensions { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string source { get; set; }



    [DataMember(Order = 8, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public Status status { get; set; }



}



[DataContract(Name = "Dimension")]
public class Dimension
{

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public Zones zones { get; set; }



}

[DataContract(Name = "Zones")]
public class Zones
{

 [DataMember(Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string zonelabel { get; set; }



}
```

When this is serialized to JSON I get something like  the following

```
{
"dataset": {
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "zones": {
                "label": "Type of Meat"

            }
        },
        {
            "zones": {
                "label": "Year",


                }
            }
        },
        {
            "zones": {
                "label": "contents",

                }
            }
        }
    ],
  ,
   "source": "Blah",        
    "status": {
        "StatusString": "150:..,151:..,152:.."
    },

}
```

}

My problem is my my dimensions can have one or more 'zones' so I really need the Json like this -

```
{
"dataset": {
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "Zone 1 - Type of Meat": {
                "label": "Type of Meat"

            }
        },
        {
            "Zone 2 - Year": {
                "label": "Year",


                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Zone 3 - Contents": {
                "label": "contents",

                }
            }
        }
    ],
  ,
   "source": "blah",        
    "status": {

"StatusString": "150:..,151:..,152:.."
    },

}
}
```

Also the  dimension class is serialized into an array in Json - Again Id just like to have my 'zone' as a comma separated list not in an array , if that makes sense -

Appreciate any pointers as new to this
Thanks